# Simple SQLAlchemy query filter in python

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to select all rows in a sql table where the first four characters of a text column match a certain string. (The backend database is a sqlite instance with limited column types, so bear with me)

The code I've written for the select is this:

```
    rows = SECtable.query.filter(str(SECtable.date)[:4] == str(matchingString)).all()
```

What am I doing wrong here? The query never matches any rows

Comment: Don't forget that you can easily debug the query generated by leaving off the "all()" and printing the resulting query. So, `query = SECtable.query.filter(...); print query`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `SECtable.date == 'some_string'`, this produces an expression (`sqlalchemy.sql.expression.BinaryExpression`), which will be evaluated when you execute the query.

`str(SECtable.date)[:4] == str(matchingString)` is evaluated immediately, it produces the string representation of `SECtable.date` (i'd guess `'SECTable.date'`), and compares all but the fist for characters to `str(matchingString)`. so what you're writing here is basically:

```
'able.date' == str(matchingString)
```

which will probably evaluate to false, so you end up with `filter(False)`.

`sqlalchemy` provides a `endswith` functionality you could use in this case:

```
rows = SECtable.query.filter(SECtable.date.endswith(matchingString)).all()
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use SQLAlchemy's implementation of SQL's LIKE.

See the following documentation:

- http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/tutorial.html#common-filter-operators
- http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.operators.ColumnOperators.like
- http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/ru/latest/orm/query.html